# Angular - cannot send POST request to log in user and don't know whats wrong?

Tags: angularjs, post, authentication

I am trying to write a post request to log in a user and nothing works. I can't see why and would be happy about any help! Thanks!!

My controller:

```
'use strict';
app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $state, $http){
    $scope.submitLogin=function(email,password)
        return $http.post('/login', {email:$scope.email,   password:$scope.password })
```

//since i have ng-model="email"- I don't actually need to pass in $scope.email but can pass in only email ?!

```
         .then(function(success){
            if (sucess){
             console.log(success)
             $state.go('stories')
            }
            else {
             console.log('error')
            }
          })
        .catch(function(err){
         console.log("bad")
        })
      })
```

Part of the HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label ng-model="email">email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label ng-model="password">password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" required />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" ng-click="submitLogin()">login</button>
</form>
```

State:

```
'use strict';
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  controller:'loginController',
  templateUrl: '/browser/app/login/login.html'
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to put ng-model="email" to your input not in label.

Comment: Let me know if it still doesn't work when you put the ng-model to your input.

Comment: Thank you. It still doesn't work and im getting this weird error: Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/ng/areq?p0=loginController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

Answer (score 1):

Put ng-model in input tag.

```
$scope.submitlogin=function(){
        data={
               email:$scope.email,
               password:$scope.password
              }
           $http.post('/login',data).success(function(){

          });
    }
```

try in this way.It might work.